# Issue while displaying trailing zeroes in Excel with StyleFrame library in Python

Tags: pandas, formatting, precision, export-to-excel, styleframe

While using the StyleFrame library to write into an excel file, I am not able to retain 3 decimal digits if there are trailing zeroes.

For example, consider the following dataframe:

[image: dataframe df with two columns, "Security Name" and "MGEAFE %Port"]

Next, I write this dataframe into a StyleFrame object for data formatting and finally, write the StyleFrame object into an excel file:

```
sf = StyleFrame(df)
sf = sf.apply_headers_style(...)
sf = sf.apply_column_style(...)
sf.to_excel(writer, float_format="%.3f")
```

Here's my output:

[image: output]

What I would like to do is, show 0.08 as 0.080 as my float format suggests "%.3f" in the to_excel() call.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since `df.to_excel(writer, float_format='%.3f')` does not provide the expected output, `sf.to_excel(writer, float_format="%.3f")` would not either (`StyleFrame.to_excel` passes kwargs that it does not recognize to `pandas.DataFrame.to_excel`).

You can get it to work by using a custom `number_format` when styling the column. Pass `number_format='0.000'` (`'0.000'` is the cell format that Excel uses to denote 3 decimal places) to the `Styler` object that you use to style the `MGEAFE %port` column.

```
from StyleFrame import StyleFrame, Styler


df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0.021, 0.029, 0.080]})
StyleFrame(df, Styler(number_format='0.000')).to_excel('test.xlsx').save()
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much, DeepSpace. :)